# App.startup path does not work in my visual studio project?

Tags: c#, sql

There is no error in this code but when i insert the values,they are not actually inserted in database.
Here is my connection string class :

```
      public class DBConn
   {

   public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
   {

      string sDBPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\App_Data\Database3.mdf";

      string connStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='" + sDBPath + "';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

       return new SqlConnection(connStr);
   }
}
```

and in this class i call the connection string class :

```
        string query = "INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "')";
        SqlConnection con = DBConn.GetConnection();

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query,con);
        con.Open();
        using (con)
        {
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Insert");
        }
```

Comment: Did you check results of sql commands?

Comment: You can put a break point at string sDBPath and check what path string you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    // Do work here; connection closed on following line.
}
```

- Your use of the `using` statement is not recommended and leads to
  problems.  You have to instantiate the resource object *inside* the
  `using` statement! It's scope or lifetime is now limited to the
  statement block and will be properly garbage collected. The way you
  use it (by passing an already instantiated object into the `using`
  statement) the objects remains valid although not properly accessible
  since it was never properly closed or disposed. [MSDN - using
  statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). So instead     of creating the connection and passing it
  around your application        (bad practice) you should create the
  connection settings (connection     string) and the query and use
  them to create a connection resource       inside a using statement
  everytime you need a connection. This way       the resource is
  always correctly disposed. The provided link gives       you an
  example how to use a using statement.
- Check your connection string well if all provided information is
  valid or all needed information is provided (e.g. username and password).
- Check database settings (e.g. permissions)
- `SqlConnection` class has an event called `InfoMessage`. In case the
  connection produces any warnings or errors you will get notified.
- Check your database (e.g. log) for the occurance of errors.